# Set up local storage path for all users

Tags: local-storage

Hi I want to set local storage variable for all windows users. Which i can set/retrieve data from logged in by any user.
Currently i am trying to set from jQuery

```
localStorage.setItem('titles', titles.text());
```

but it stored on location C://Users/{username}/AppData/myapp. I want to change path of it.

Comment: I don't think you can do that without seriously messing with the browser installation.

Comment: Thanks Thilo, 
I have created a offline package. So i want to set local storage variable for all user. My requirement is that any user bookmark any content then it always appear whenever any user log in. Have you any idea for it or other way to do?